# Can't access Google App Engine Endpoint using Default URL

Tags: google-app-engine, version, google-cloud-endpoints

I've deployed a google endpoint service to my app engine. The app engine project version is 1-2-12, and I set it to default version. I have verified that the deployment was successful via the log:

```
Endpoints: https://1-2-12-dot-appid.appspot.com/_ah/api/server@v1 Saved
```

Based on the google documentation, I should be able to access my end point via the default url:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/test_deploy#accessing_backend_api_versions_deployed_to_an_application_default_version

The error returned is: Not Found

So the issue is I can't access the endpoint via the project's **default url**:

https://appid.appspot.com/_ah/api/server/v1/platformidentity

And I can only access the end point via its **version specific url**:

https://1-2-12-dot-appid.appspot.com/_ah/api/server/v1/platformidentity

If I try accessing the API explorer:

- default url https://appid.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer gives me empty Services
- version specific url https://1-2-12-dot-appid.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer gives me the correct Endpoint service as expected.

Comment: Sure sounds like you haven't set that version to be the default.  Better recheck that in the developer console.

Comment: It's definitely set correctly to default. Anyway, we gave up and started using Jersey instead.